# Have 2 elements share same line with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

If I am justifying a series of elements with flexbox is it possible to make 2 elements share a line?

For instance take this example:

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50px;
}
.outer .inner {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">1</div>
  <div class="inner">2</div>
  <div class="inner">3</div>
  <div class="inner">4</div>
  <div class="inner">5</div>
  <div class="inner">6</div>
  <div class="inner">7</div>
</div>
```

The elements are in straight column.  Is it possible to select certain elements to share a row like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried another flexbox container around the two elements you want on a row?

Comment: I cant edit the html, I am only able to use css.

Comment: Do you have to use flexbox? I wonder if using a CSS grid layout would make this easier on you.

Comment: I just checked stats and that would not work for around 15% of traffic unfortunately.  If there is no way I will just use absolute positioning and margins but I'd rather have a solution with nicer flow

Comment: Can you use Jquery?

Comment: yes, I can add jquery, I just cant change html because it will break some stuff outside on my control

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this.

What I did is set `.outer` to `flex-flow:row wrap;` and set its `width`.

and then set the `margin` of `.outer .inner:nth-child(3),.outer .inner:nth-child(4)`

By making the child 3 and 4 to have set its `margin` and `width` that will still not exceeds to width of the `.outer` so that they will still be inline to each other and the other child will occupy the whole row because their `margin` and `width` is equal to the width of the `.outer`

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 120px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.outer .inner {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-right: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.outer .inner:nth-child(3),
.outer .inner:nth-child(4){
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">1</div>
  <div class="inner">2</div>
  <div class="inner">3</div>
  <div class="inner">4</div>
  <div class="inner">5</div>
  <div class="inner">6</div>
  <div class="inner">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very clever I like it.  Forcing item to wrap with margin is not something that would have occurred to me.

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this:

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  margin:auto;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width: 50px;
}
.outer .inner {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.outer .inner:nth-child(3),.outer .inner:nth-child(4) {
  width:25px;
  position:relative;
}
.outer .inner:nth-child(3):before,.outer .inner:nth-child(4):before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:-12px;
  right:-12px;
  background:blue;
  z-index:-1;
}

.outer .inner:nth-child(3) {
  transform:translateX(-20px)
}
.outer .inner:nth-child(4) {
  transform:translateX(20px)
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">1</div>
  <div class="inner">2</div>
  <div class="inner">3</div>
  <div class="inner">4</div>
  <div class="inner">5</div>
  <div class="inner">6</div>
  <div class="inner">7</div>
</div>
```